# Adding Another Column to a Dataframe from One Json File

Tags: python, pandas

I am interested in trying to add another column into my data frame from a dataset but I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. I am using the following code and here is an example of the JSON I am using. If I remove one of the two other columns, other than hostname it works perfectly fine.

```
file = open("assets.json",)
file_json = json.load(file)

df = (pd
      .concat(objs=[pd.json_normalize(data=x) for x in file_json])
      .filter(items=["asset.hostname", "plugin.solution", "plugin.cve"])
      .dropna(how="any")
      .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
      .explode(column="solution")
      .explode(column="cve")
      .groupby(by="hostname", as_index=False)
      .solution.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
      .cve.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
      )
print(df)
```

```
[
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "John Smith",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-777-7777"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update .NET Core Runtime to version 3.1.23, 5.0.15 or 6.0.3.",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "ACCEPTED",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-999-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Add and enable registry value Nonsense:\n  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\Nonsense\\Nonsense\\Config\\Nonsene3\n\nAdditionally, on 64 Bit OS systems, Add and enable registry value Nonsense64:\n\n  - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Stuff\\Nonsense64\\Config\\Supernonsense",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Frank Castle",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "Computer2",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update to Version 7.3",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer2",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-999-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update to version 6.0",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
],
[
    {
        "asset": {
            "agent_uuid": "Jan Thomas",
            "device_type": "redacted",
            "fqdn": "redacted",
            "hostname": "computer1",
            "ipv4": "redacted",
            "ipv6": "redacted",
            "last_authenticated_results": "redacted",
            "mac_address": "redacted",
            "netbios_name": "redacted",
            "network_id": "0redacted",
            "operating_system": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "tracked": true,
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "first_found": "redacted",
        "indexed": "redacted",
        "last_found": "redacted",
        "output": "redacted",
        "plugin": {
            "bid": [
                179635
            ],
            "checks_for_default_account": false,
            "checks_for_malware": false,
            "cpe": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "cve": [
                "CVE-888-9999"
            ],
            "cvss_base_score": 0.0,
            "cvss_temporal_score": 0.4,
            "cvss_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "authentication": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_base_score": 0.8,
            "cvss3_temporal_score": 0,
            "cvss3_temporal_vector": {
                "exploitability": "redacted",
                "raw": "redacted",
                "remediation_level": "redacted",
                "report_confidence": "redacted"
            },
            "cvss3_vector": {
                "access_complexity": "redacted",
                "access_vector": "redacted",
                "availability_impact": "redacted",
                "confidentiality_impact": "redacted",
                "integrity_impact": "redacted",
                "raw": "Credacted"
            },
            "description": "redacted",
            "exploit_available": false,
            "exploit_framework_canvas": false,
            "exploit_framework_core": false,
            "exploit_framework_d2_elliot": false,
            "exploit_framework_exploithub": false,
            "exploit_framework_metasploit": false,
            "exploitability_ease": "redacted",
            "exploited_by_malware": false,
            "exploited_by_nessus": false,
            "family": "redacted",
            "family_id": 7,
            "has_patch": false,
            "id": 179635,
            "in_the_news": false,
            "modification_date": "redacted",
            "name": "Bad Exploit 1",
            "patch_publication_date": "redacted",
            "publication_date": "redacted",
            "risk_factor": "redacted",
            "see_also": [
                "redacted"
            ],
            "solution": "Update on Microsoft Store",
            "stig_severity": "redacted",
            "synopsis": "redacted",
            "unsupported_by_vendor": false,
            "vpr": {
                "drivers": {
                    "age_of_vuln": {
                        "lower_bound": 8,
                        "upper_bound": 30
                    },
                    "cvss3_impact_score": 0.9,
                    "exploit_code_maturity": "redacted",
                    "product_coverage": "redacted",
                    "threat_intensity_last28": "redacted",
                    "threat_sources_last28": [
                        "redacted"
                    ]
                },
                "score": 0,
                "updated": "redacted"
            },
            "vuln_publication_date": "redacted",
            "xrefs": [
            ]
        },
        "port": {
            "port": 0,
            "protocol": "TCP"
        },
        "scan": {
            "schedule_uuid": "redacted",
            "started_at": "redacted",
            "uuid": "redacted"
        },
        "severity": "redacted",
        "severity_default_id": 3,
        "severity_id": 3,
        "severity_modification_type": "NONE",
        "state": "open"
    }
]
]
```

I get the following error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\Desktop\Python Projects\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns.py", line 65, in <module>
    .cve.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
     ^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5989, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cve'
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So, if I remove either the .explode(column="cve") and .cve.apply(lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x))) I get this output.

```
            hostname                                           solution
0          computer1  Upgrade to version 12
1      computer2  Upgrade to version 12
2    computer3  Upgrade to version 12
3     computer4  Upgrade to version 12
4       computer5  Upgrade to version 12
..               ...                                                ...
637      computer638  Upgrade to version 12
638     computer639  Upgrade to version 12
639     computer640  Upgrade to version 12
640   computer641  Upgrade to version 12
641   computer642  Upgrade to version 12

[642 rows x 2 columns]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I get a similar output when I remove the solutions part of the code.

```
            hostname                                           cve
0          computer1  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-888-8888
1      computer2  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-888-8888
2    computer3  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-555-5555, CVE-666-6666
3     computer4  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-555-5555, CVE-666-6666
4       computer5  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-756-9642, CVE-444-4444
..               ...                                                ...
637      computer638  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-999-9999
638     computer639  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-756-9642, CVE-444-4444
639     computer640  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-756-9642, CVE-444-4444
640   computer641  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-555-5555, CVE-666-6666
641   computer642  CVE-7777-7777, CVE-888-8888
```

Jason Baker, output is exactly what I am looking for.

```
    hostname                                                             solution                                       cve
0  computer1  Update to 6.7, Update on Microsoft Store, Update on Microsoft Store  CVE-777-7777, CVE-999-9999, CVE-888-9999
1  computer2                                                Update to version 6.0                              CVE-999-9999
```

When I attempted to run that code I got the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\Desktop\Python Projects\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns\Exports.Vulns.py", line 61, in <module>
    .explode(column=["solution", "cve"])
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Sinpo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 8887, in explode
    raise ValueError("columns must have matching element counts")
ValueError: columns must have matching element counts
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Due to some weirdness in my real data vs my sample data, Jason Baker helped me figure out code that did manage to work for what I needed it to do.

Comment: I am not sure what youare doing here, but the column CVE is not available after the groupby('homename') line.  If you remove the line that starts with .cve, you will see you have two column dataframe with just hostname and solution.  So, youare getting a KeyError CVE.

Comment: whats the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

Code:

```
df = (pd
      .concat(objs=[pd.json_normalize(data=x) for x in file_json])
      .filter(items=["asset.hostname", "plugin.solution", "plugin.cve"])
      .dropna(how="any")
      .rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])
      )

solution_df = (df
               .explode(column="solution")
               .groupby(by="hostname", as_index=False)
               .solution.apply(func=lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
               )

cve_df = (df
          .explode(column="cve")
          .groupby(by="hostname", as_index=False)
          .cve.apply(func=lambda x: ", ".join(map(str, x)))
          )


final_df = pd.merge(left=solution_df, right=cve_df, on="hostname", how="outer")
print(final_df)
```

Output:

```
    hostname                                                             solution                                       cve
0  computer1  Update to 6.7, Update on Microsoft Store, Update on Microsoft Store  CVE-777-7777, CVE-999-9999, CVE-888-9999
1  computer2                                                Update to version 6.0                              CVE-999-9999
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: oh good please mark as solved when you get time

Comment: I got an error code from it, so I am not sure what I did wrong on that.

Comment: whats the error and what pandas version are you using

Comment: The Error is listed above, and I am using Pandas 2.0.3

Comment: I'm using 2.1.1 but I think the issue is the actual data isn't close enough to the sample data. solution or cve dont have the same elements perhaps one isnt a list or something on a row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255384/discussion-between-lobermeyer-and-jason-baker).